# Do demons (Asuras, Rakshasas, Pisachas, Nagas, etc) reveal false religions to humans according to Hindu scriptures?

Tags: puranas, other-religions, asuras, rakshasa, itihasa

According to the Puranas, Vishnu as Buddha revealed a false religion, which we know today as Buddhism, to deceive the Daityas who were using the Vedas to acquire power.

Similarly, do Hindu scriptures talk about the opposite: demons revealing false religions to delude and mislead humans?

Comment: Now this is fine with better words !!!

Comment: Buddhism as understood by its followers is wrong  not the actual teaching according bannaje govindacharaya there were 6 different schools of budhism even today. Buddha's teaching were revered and studied as prashanti Upanishad in deva loka  According to  bannaje no teaching of avatara can be against Vedas Buddha preached through his silence He didn't say Veda is Apramana  but he insisted against animal sacrifice performed during yagna God is Sunya  the whole universe is shanikam   sun=bliss ya=jnana or Knowledge God is gnaanaAnanda swaroopa SHANIKA= EVER CHANGING